# Karma jasmine Angular 1.6.2 testing filter throws error Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr]

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am working on testing my AngularJS code, and I am having a problem that all the answers I could find wouldn't fix.
I am trying to test a filter that looks like this:

```
app.filter('capitalize', function(){
    return function(val){
        if( val && typeof val === 'string'){
            return val.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + val.substr(1).replace('_', ' ');
        }
    };
});
```

my `app` is defined as :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ["ui.router", "ui.bootstrap", "ngSanitize", "pascalprecht.translate", "angular-google-analytics", 
"ngStorage", "jsonFormatter", "selectize", "toaster"]);
```

My test looks like:

```
describe('Filters Unit Test Suite:', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
        angular.mock.module('myApp');
    });

    describe('capitalize filter', function() {
        var capitalizeFilter;
        beforeEach(inject(function(_$filter_) {
            capitalizeFilter = _$filter('capitalize');
        }));

        it('should capitalize the first letter of a string', function() {
            expect(capitalizeFilter('hello')).toEqual('Hello');
        });
    });
});
```

Every piece of code here is pulled from a different file, namely `filters.js`, `app.js`, and `fitler.test.js` respectively.
I used these documentations [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/testing-angularjs-with-jasmine-and-karma-part-2#bonus-testing-an-angular-filter) and the official AngularJs testing page [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing).

I already tested almost all the response similar to question like this asked here, but none seems to be working.

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

I might have skipped a response, if you think so, please add the link in comment.
I have spend almost three days looking, searching here on stackoverflow for the reason why, and to find how to correct that. That is too much of my time I already lost, and I feel like I am to close to this to see what I am missing, that's why I seek your help.

Thank you.

Just in case, here is how I put the files in my karma config file:

```
  files:[

  'src/main/resources/assets/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
   'src/main/resources/assets/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
   'src/main/resources/assets/bower_components/ngstorage/ngStorage.js',
   'src/main/resources/assets/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'src/main/resources/assets/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
  'src/main/resources/assets/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js',
  'src/main/resources/assets/js/vendor/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.2.4.min.js',
  'src/main/resources/assets/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
  'src/main/resources/assets/bower_components/highcharts/highcharts.js',
  'src/main/resources/assets/bower_components/highcharts/highcharts-more.js',
  'src/main/resources/assets/bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate.js',
  'src/main/resources/assets/bower_components/moment/min/moment.min.js',
  'src/main/resources/assets/bower_components/angular-translate-loader-static-files/angular-translate-loader-static-files.js',
  'src/main/resources/assets/bower_components/angular-google-analytics/dist/angular-google-analytics.min.js',
  'src/main/resources/assets/bower_components/json-formatter/dist/json-formatter.js',
  'src/main/resources/assets/bower_components/selectize/dist/js/standalone/selectize.js',
  'src/main/resources/assets/bower_components/angular-selectize2/dist/angular-selectize.js',
  'src/main/resources/assets/bower_components/AngularJS-Toaster/toaster.min.js',

  'src/main/resources/assets/js/angular/app.js',
  'src/main/resources/assets/js/angular/filters.js',
  'src/test/resources/assets/js/angular/filters.test.js'
]
```

[image: Error message image]

Comment: can you post the exact error you're getting?

Comment: @clever_bassi I edited the question and added an image of the error I am having.

Comment: What is AuthService? Where are you using it?

Comment: It's a service that `app.run()` is using to authenticate a user login

Comment: in my understanding, you are not injecting the service and trying to use it somewhere. without looking at full code i cannot tell. Please create a plunker with your code

Comment: @clever_bassi I am not using it anywhere in filters. It is being used in just one factory that grands access to the user when trying to login into the web app. And again in the `app.run()` as I mentioned before. That all the information I can provide, as I can't post all the code, for security reasons.

Comment: After a long run, I finally figured out why I was having the error I mentioned. With the help o your answer @clever_bassi, I went back, and found out the the `AuthService` was a module which is local into my project. the service was defined by one of the developer I am working with, and I was looking for it in the wrong place. And this showed me that I still have a long way to go learning the one page website which is AngularJS.

Comment: I'm glad it worked. For future reference, I have seen this error generally happens when you're trying to reference a service that doesn't exist by the exact same name.

Answer (score 0):

The error I got on running your code is this:
[image]
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/E64Se/111/) is the working fiddle.

I believe you had not added the angular-ui library to it. I added the library and it works fine. Add the following link and try your code again.

```
http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.min.js
```

Comment: If you look at the question, I provided a list of all that is in my `karma.conf.js` file in the `files[]` property, and the angular-ui-library is there. I am using v0.4.2.

Answer (score 0):

After a long run, I finally figured out why I was having the error I mentioned. With the help o your answer @clever_bassi, I went back, and found out the the `AuthService` was a module which is local into my project. the service was defined by one of the developer I am working with, and I was looking for it in the wrong place. And this showed me that I still have a long way to go learning the one page website which is AngularJS.